# rhandsontable doesn´t update with selectizeGroupUI

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, rhandsontable

I am building a Shiny app that displays a different rhandsontable for each radioButton choice ("A", "B"). This app includes a callModule of two variables ("Petal.Width", "Species").
The problem is that the table doesnt update when you change the selectizeGroupUI choices.
Example: filtering by Species = "versicolor" and viewing both tables, the tables look like:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

when we change the Species filter, the table we are currently viewing updates, but when we change the radioButton choice, this new table doesnt update.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

This is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(rhandsontable)
library(DT)


data1 <- iris %>% mutate(Petal.Width = if_else(iris$Petal.Width>0.4, ">0.4", "<=0.4")) %>% 
  select("Petal.Width", "Species", "Petal.Length")

data1 <- data1[c(1:3,44,51:53,102:105),]

data2 <- iris %>% mutate(Petal.Width = if_else(iris$Petal.Width>0.4, ">0.4", "<=0.4")) %>% 
  select("Petal.Width", "Species", "Sepal.Length")

data2 <- data2[c(1:3,44,51:53,102:105),]

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "black",
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Aranceles",
    titleWidth = 200,
    uiOutput("logoutbtn")
  ),
  
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE),
  
  dashboardBody(
    
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(
        height = "2100px",
        width = 12,
        selected = "Tab1",
        
        # Pestaña Propuesta incrementos pre pagas####        
        tabPanel("Tab1",
                 
                 fluidRow(column(
                   width = 6,
                   selectizeGroupUI(
                     id = "my-filters1",
                     inline = TRUE,
                     params = list(
                       Petal.Width= list(
                         inputId = "Petal.Width",
                         title = "Petal.Width"
                       ),
                       Species = list(
                         inputId = "Species",
                         title = "Species"
                     )))),
                 
                 fluidRow(
                   basicPage(
                     radioButtons(
                       inputId = "value",
                       choices = list("A", "B"),
                       label = "label"
                     ))),
                 
                 fluidRow(basicPage(uiOutput('table')))
      ))
  )
)))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_reac1<- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters1",
    data = data1,
    vars = c("Petal.Width","Species")
  )
  
  data_reac2<- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters1",
    data = data2,
    vars = c("Petal.Width","Species")
  )
  
  
  rv_data1 <- reactiveValues(table_rv1 = NULL)
  
  observeEvent((input$value == "A" & 
                  ((is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                     (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                     (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                     (is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])))) || 
                 (input$value == "B" & 
                    ((is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                       (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                       (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                       (is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])))),{
                         data_reac1.1 <- data_reac1() %>%
                           mutate("new_var" = 0) 
                         rv_data1$table_rv1<- data_reac1.1})
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$table1)){
      mytable_rv1 <- as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$table1))
      mytable_rv1[,4] <- (mytable_rv1[,3]*2)
      rv_data1$table_rv1 <- mytable_rv1}
  })
  
  table_1.1 <- reactive({
    rhandsontable(rv_data1$table_rv1)
  })
  
  
  rv_data2 <- reactiveValues(table_rv2 = NULL)
  
  observeEvent((input$value == "A" & 
                  ((is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                     (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                     (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                     (is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])))) || 
                 (input$value == "B" & 
                    ((is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                       (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                       (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                       (is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])))),{
                         data_reac2.1 <- data_reac2() %>%
                           mutate("new_var" = 0) 
                         rv_data2$table_rv2<- data_reac2.1})
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$table2)){
      mytable_rv2 <- as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$table2))
      mytable_rv2[,4] <- (mytable_rv2[,3]*2)
      rv_data2$table_rv2 <- mytable_rv2}
  })
  
  table_2.1 <- reactive({
    rhandsontable(rv_data2$table_rv2)
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    table_1.1() 
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    table_2.1()
  })
  
  
  output$table <- renderUI({
    if(input$value == "A"){rHandsontableOutput("table1")}
    else{rHandsontableOutput("table2")}})
  
 }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

We tried considering in observeEvent every possible input combination.

````
                  ((is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                     (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                     (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                     (is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])))) || 
                 (input$value == "B" & 
                    ((is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                       (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                       (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                       (is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])))```
````

Comment: Is it really your wish to show different tables on changing the `value` input? I think that it would be much more straightforward to filter from the same dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for answering @David. Yes, it´s what we want to do because in the actual code the table from input "A" has one formula and the table from input "B" has a different formula. Choices "A" and "B" are not categories from a variable, they indicate what formula to use, that´s why we can´t filter from the same dataframe.